# how to write multidimensional array from cplex to Ms Excel

Tags: excel, cplex, opl

I can read a multidimensional array(e.g 3 dimensions from excel). But writing a a 3 dimensional array from the cplex opl solution back to excel seems to be a problem. Can someone please help out?

Comment: Welcome to SO. As is, your question is a bit too broad for anyone to be able to help you. The expectation normally is that you try to solve the problems and then present the community of what you've done so far and what specific problem you need help with tackling.

Answer (score 0):

I gave an example at https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014419923&ps=25

The trick is to turn your array into a tuple set and then use SheetWrite with that tuple set.

.mod

```
range A=1..2;
range B=1..3;
range C=1..4;


dvar int X[A][B][C];

subject to
{
forall(a in A,b in B,c in C) X[a][b][c]==a*b*c;
}

tuple someTuple{
int a;
int b;
int c;
int value;
};


{someTuple} someSet = {<i,j,k,X[i][j][k]> | i in A, j in B, k in C};
```

.dat

```
SheetConnection sheet("excel.xlsx");

someSet to SheetWrite(sheet,"A1:D24");
```

Comment: This is very helpful. Thanks a lot. just a newbie here. Will adhere to the standards